# Postman request vs Local (server) request

Tags: c#, https, postman, http-status-code-403, fiddler

I'm developing a C# application to communicate with an external API. I'm using HttpClient to send requests to that API. The question is:

- If I make the request through Postman or even through my application (but with Fiddler open) I get a response with 200 code and with the information I want.
- If I make the request through my application (which is running on localhost) or even through PowerShell, I get code 403.

PS: The code I'm using in C# was generated by Postman.

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9xah.png)

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://betting.begmedia.pt/api/v2/me/bets/ended");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Client", secretToken);
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.36.0");
        
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`
```

Comment: It seems very odd that your application with Fiddler running produces a 200 but with Fiddler off (and the exact same application code) produces a 403. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I will lean towards it being a coincidence. I see no reason why fiddler decides if you get a success or failed response. You can try resetting your router. Is there a reason you specify the postman user agent in your code?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove the User-Agent, it's not supposed to be there. I tried sending the same request via Powershell from another computer I have at home (same network) and I also got 200, so I'm assuming it must be some configuration on my computer, right?

Comment: If there is a difference between proxy on and off then the target server uses most likely TLS fingerprinting. Different application stacks use slightly different (valid) TLS settings. Those differences can be detected and fingerprinted on server side and based on that an application is allowed or rejected.